# How to prevent first/last bars from being cut off in a chart with time scale

Tags: momentjs, chart.js

How do I prevent the first and last bars from being cut off (showing half)?

I need to show the short month names on the x-axis. I've tried playing around with various min/max settings, but I can't seem to get it right.

[image: Example]

```js
var graphData = {
  dates: [
    '2016-06-01',
    '2016-07-01',
    '2016-08-01',
    '2016-09-01',
    '2016-10-01',
    '2016-11-01',
    '2016-12-01',
    '2017-01-01',
    '2017-02-01',
    '2017-03-01',
    '2017-04-01',
    '2017-05-01'
  ],
  wins: [23, 5, 13, 24, 8, 11, 23, 5, 13, 24, 8, 11],
  draws: [2, 1, 2, 0, 2, 2, 3, 1, 2, 4, 0, 1],
  losses: [3, 1, 2, 10, 8, 8, 3, 1, 2, 10, 8, 8],
  winRates: [50, 40, 72, 30, 46, 80, 50, 40, 72, 30, 46, 80]
};

var winsMax = Math.max.apply(Math, graphData.wins);
var lossesMax = Math.max.apply(Math, graphData.losses);

var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: "bar",
  data: {
    labels: graphData.dates.map((date) => moment(date)),
    datasets: [
      {
        type: "bar",
        backgroundColor: "green",
        hoverBackgroundColor: "green",
        data: graphData.wins,
        yAxisID: "winsAndLosses"
      },
      {
        type: "bar",
        backgroundColor: "red",
        hoverBackgroundColor: "red",
        data: graphData.losses.map((i) => -i),
        yAxisID: "winsAndLosses"
      },
      {
        type: "line",
        data: graphData.winRates,
        fill: true,
        backgroundColor: "gray",
        pointRadius: 0,
        pointHoverRadius: 0,
        yAxisID: "winRate"
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    legend: {
      display: false
    },
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        type: "time",
        time: {
          unit: "month",
          displayFormats: {
            month: "MMM"
          }
        },
        stacked: true,
        gridLines: {
          display: false
        },
        ticks: {
          callback: (label) => label.toUpperCase(),
          fontSize: 10     
        }
      }],
      yAxes: [
        {
          id: "winsAndLosses",
          stacked: true,
          ticks: {
            min: (lossesMax + 10) * -1,
            max: winsMax + 10,
            callback: (label) => Math.abs(label) // TODO: Localization (number formatting).
          },
          display: false
        },
        {
          id: "winRate",
          ticks: {
            min: 0,
            max: 100,
            stepSize: 10,
            callback: (label) => label + "%", // TODO: Localization (number formatting).
            fontSize: 10
          }
        }
      ]
    }
}
});
```

```css
.myChartDiv {
  max-width: 800px;
  max-height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/chart.js@latest/dist/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="myChartDiv">
      <canvas id="myChart" width="800" height="400"></canvas>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 55, accepted):

There's a setting called offset which seems to work for me:

```
xAxes: [{
     offset: true
  }]
```

```js
var graphData = {
  dates: [
    '2016-06-01',
    '2016-07-01',
    '2016-08-01',
    '2016-09-01',
    '2016-10-01',
    '2016-11-01',
    '2016-12-01',
    '2017-01-01',
    '2017-02-01',
    '2017-03-01',
    '2017-04-01',
    '2017-05-01'
  ],
  wins: [23, 5, 13, 24, 8, 11, 23, 5, 13, 24, 8, 11],
  draws: [2, 1, 2, 0, 2, 2, 3, 1, 2, 4, 0, 1],
  losses: [3, 1, 2, 10, 8, 8, 3, 1, 2, 10, 8, 8],
  winRates: [50, 40, 72, 30, 46, 80, 50, 40, 72, 30, 46, 80]
};

var winsMax = Math.max.apply(Math, graphData.wins);
var lossesMax = Math.max.apply(Math, graphData.losses);

var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: "bar",
  data: {
    labels: graphData.dates.map((date) => moment(date)),
    datasets: [
      {
        type: "bar",
        backgroundColor: "green",
        hoverBackgroundColor: "green",
        data: graphData.wins,
        yAxisID: "winsAndLosses"
      },
      {
        type: "bar",
        backgroundColor: "red",
        hoverBackgroundColor: "red",
        data: graphData.losses.map((i) => -i),
        yAxisID: "winsAndLosses"
      },
      {
        type: "line",
        data: graphData.winRates,
        fill: true,
        backgroundColor: "gray",
        pointRadius: 0,
        pointHoverRadius: 0,
        yAxisID: "winRate"
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    legend: {
      display: false
    },
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        type: "time",
        time: {
          unit: "month",
          displayFormats: {
            month: "MMM"
          }
        },
        stacked: true,
        gridLines: {
          display: false
        },
        ticks: {
          callback: (label) => label.toUpperCase(),
          fontSize: 10     
        },
        offset:true
      }],
      yAxes: [
        {
          id: "winsAndLosses",
          stacked: true,
          ticks: {
            min: (lossesMax + 10) * -1,
            max: winsMax + 10,
            callback: (label) => Math.abs(label) // TODO: Localization (number formatting).
          },
          display: false
        },
        {
          id: "winRate",
          ticks: {
            min: 0,
            max: 100,
            stepSize: 10,
            callback: (label) => label + "%", // TODO: Localization (number formatting).
            fontSize: 10
          }
        }
      ]
    }
}
});
```

```css
.myChartDiv {
  max-width: 800px;
  max-height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/chart.js@latest/dist/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="myChartDiv">
      <canvas id="myChart" width="800" height="400"></canvas>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried this with no effect at all. First and last lines are still cut off.

Comment: You're right. Try `xAxes: [{offset: true}]` instead

Can be found here: http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/ in the first chart

Comment: Wow that worked! Thank you very much - if you update your answer I can upvote it.

Comment: Made my day! ✌️

Comment: thanks, the offset definitely works, but for me it added excessively large padding which looks bad. I could not find any way on how to configure its size. I ended up adding dummy (empty) data to the last position of my dataset which fixed this problem. My chart contains hundreds of bars and this may not be usable if you have only couple of bars